# Can subordinate user ID be used to grant file system permissions?

Tags: linux, users, namespace

Suppose I have user "myuser" with uid/gid "1001", and files "/etc/subuid" & "/etc/subgid" with the following content:

```
myuser:100000:65536
```

Can this setup somehow be used to allow user "myuser" to access files with owner "100000"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes with the help of the *setuid root* utilities [`newuidmap`](https://manpages.debian.org/uidmap/newuidmap.1) and [`newgidmap`](https://manpages.debian.org/uidmap/newgidmap.1) working along with [`/etc/subuid`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/passwd/subuid.5) and [`/etc/subgid`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/passwd/subgid.5).

Tools like *podman*, *docker*, or LXC all require these *setuid root* utilities installed to work in rootless/unprivileged mode with a normal user. Without these tools there are not enough rights available to bootstrap this.

All the lengthy explanations are in the [user namespaces](https://manpages.debian.org/user_namespaces.7#User_and_group_ID_mappings:_uid_map_and_gid_map) manpage that should be read to understand how the features can be used. In short, once the user namespace is created (with an unprivileged operation), the specific pseudo-files `/proc/<PID>/{uid,gid}_map` can be written once and only once to set the mappings. With correct (host) privileges, spare *uid*/*gid* ranges, as allowed in `/etc/sub{uid,gid}`, can then be mapped in the user namespace.

The user *myuser* itself (without the assistance of any special command) can write to those pseudo-files, but:

- is allowed only to have itself (host *uid* 1001) mapped into one *uid* in the user namespace (the obvious possibly useful choices being itself again or 0 for *root*). This has to be done anyway from an other process, since the new process is temporarily without mapping in the newly created user namespace. As any non-mapped *uid* gets translated to the overflow *uid* (by default 65534 aka *nobody*) until "resolved", it thus can't write to its own `/proc/<PID>/uid_map` file. Even if it becomes *root* in this namespace, as it can affect only *root* which is host *uid* 1001, this is useless. System calls (and commands using them) are all made to not allow rights escalation. In addition to failing with `EPERM` etc. they can also fail with `EINVAL` when trying to alter a mapped *uid* (ie: host *uid* 1001) into a non-mapped *uid*.
- same for groups, with the additional restriction that it must first forfeit the ability to use [`setgroups`](https://manpages.debian.org/setgroups.2) before being able to write in `/proc/<PID>/gid_map` (that's to avoid being able to *remove* oneself from a group to *evade* restrictions to files added by being part of this group).

So *uid* 100000 would of course not be reachable: *setuid root* tools *are* required.

The goal here is to map the normal user *myuser* with *uid* 1001 (allowed in mappings by `newuidmap` in addition to the subordinate ids) as the *root* user (*uid* 0), as well as *also* map at least the host *uid* 100000 inside the user namespace: this allows to change one to the other by (the user namespace's) *root* when needed. Here I'll just map just the additional 100000 to ... 100000 again. I'll do the same with *gid*, assuming `/etc/subgid` is a mirror of `/etc/subuid`.

Here's a practical example on how to do, using `newuidmap` and `newgidmap`, all from initial host user *myuser*. As explained above, this requires two processes, so here two shells in two terminals. The actions of these *setuid root* commands could be replaced with correctly crafted `echo` (or `printf` etc.) commands run from the (host) *root* user.

term1:

```
$ unshare --user sh
$ id -u; id -un ; id -g; id -gn; echo pid:$$
65534
nobody
65534
nogroup
pid:13273
```

term2 (reusing previous *pid* value in the commands):

```
$ newuidmap 13273 0 1001 1 100000 100000 1
$ newgidmap 13273 0 1001 1 100000 100000 1
```

term1 again (`exec sh` just to have the shell display the "resolved" and "upgraded" status):

```
$ id -u; id -un ; id -g; id -gn
0
root
0
root
$ exec sh
#

# touch mytest
# chown 100000:100000 mytest
```

term2 (which here displays the same as in *term1*, since the mapping was chosen with the same values):

```
$ ls -l mytest
-rw-r--r--. 1 100000 100000 0 Apr 21 18:00 mytest
$ touch mytest
touch: cannot touch 'mytest': Permission denied
```

term1:

```
# chown 100001:100001 mytest
chown: changing ownership of 'mytest': Invalid argument
# chown root:root mytest
```

term2:

```
$ ls -l mytest
-rw-r--r--. 1 myuser myuser 0 Apr 21 18:00 mytest
```

Any sub process from *term1* will now have control over *uid* 100000, including filesystem operations.

Bigger ranges or smarter mappings could be used, as allowed in `/etc/subuid` to affect more things or things more easily (eg: mapping 100000 to *myuser* instead, with `newuidmap 13273 0 1001 1 1001 100000 1` would have allowed to simply run `su myuser` in *term1*, which should succeed despite a few non-fatal errors). This would also allow for example to access/rescue/backup (at the filesystem level only, not other features like network) an user LXC instance which would refuse to start due to some unrelated issue.